# 2nd System.out.println() statement not executing inside twoOccurences class

Tags: java

```
public class Part3 {
public  static boolean twoOccurences(String stringa,String stringb){
    String a=stringa;
    String b=stringb;
    int index=0,count=0;
    System.out.println(index);
    if(b.indexOf(a)!=-1){
        return false;
    }else{
        System.out.println(index);
        while(index!=-1){
        index=b.indexOf(a,index);
        if(index!=-1){
            count++;
            index=index+a.length();
        }
    }
    }
    System.out.println(count>=2);
    if(count>=2)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
```

}

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println(twoOccurences("by", "A story by Abby Long"));
    System.out.println(twoOccurences("a", "banana"));
    System.out.println(twoOccurences("atg", "ctgtatgta"));
}
```

I am trying to find the occurrence of the first string in the second. For the three method calls in main, I am getting the following output:

```
0
false
0
false
0
false
```

The second System.out.println() statement isn't executing.Can someone explain the reason?

Comment: `if(b.indexOf(a)!=-1){
        return false;` So you return `false` if `b` **does** contain `a`?

Comment: Thanks a lot ,I got my error!

Comment: method u mean twoOcu.,..